# NGINX auth_request using django

Tags: django, nginx

i have a NginX with protected location at 192.168.56.108, and my django app at 192.168.56.1

here is my nginx default site config

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location /sflow-rt/ {
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /sflow-rt/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8008/;
      proxy_redirect ~^http://[^/]+(/.+)$ /sflow-rt$1;
      # insert access policy below
      auth_request /auth;
    }

        location /auth {
        internal ;
                proxy_pass http://192.168.56.1:8000/xpages/authonly;
        #proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        #proxy_set_header    X-Original-URL $scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
        #add_header          Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;
        #auth_request_set    $auth_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;
    }
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

And here is my django view that will called by 'proxy_pass [http://192.168.56.1:8000/xpages/authonly'](http://192.168.56.1:8000/xpages/authonly%27)

```
class authonly(FormView):
    template_name = 'auth_only.html'
    form_class = auth_only_form

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            print(f'REQUEST USER: {request.user}')
            return HttpResponse('authenticated',status=200)

        print('Non Authenticated User')
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})



    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(f'Cleaned data => {form.cleaned_data}')
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        try :
            user = authenticate(username = name, password=password)
            login(self.request, user)
            return HttpResponse(status=200)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Failed Auth:\n\t{traceback.format_exc()}')
            return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

That view will display a simple login screen only if user is not authenticated.

The problem is, as a 'normal' web server any non error response will carry http status 200 .. while the nginx auth_request take 200 as 'Ok to continue'.
This way will result that the login page never displayed ... since the form html also carry http status 200.

Please tell me how to fix this